# Syntax error in UPDATE statement Visual Studio C#.net

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error, sql-update, oledbcommand

I've been trying to figure out the right syntax for the UPDATE statement when coding in C#.net and using OleDbCommand.  I feel like what I have is correct, but it definitely isn't because I still am getting the error: "Syntax error in UPDATE statement".  My code is posted below for my Update button.  I have checked many sites (including Stackoverflow) to see what the correct syntax and standard is for creating SQL statements, but still haven't found the one that doesn't give me a syntax error.  Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

```
private void update_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ssize = "";
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control != null && control is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton radio = control as RadioButton;
                if (radio.Checked == true)
                {
                    ssize = control.Text;
                }
            }
        }
        OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Youth SET FName = ?, MI = ?, LName = ?, Street = ?, CityStateZip = ?, PG = ?, HomePN = ?, WorkPN = ?, CellPN = ?, YEmail = ?, PGEmail = ?, Age = ?, DOB = ?, HS = ?, Grade = ?, PrevExp = ?, SSize = ?, Allergies = ?, MedConditions = ?, Avail = ?, FirstDep = ?, SecDep = ?, ThirdDep = ?, Fundraiser_1 = ?, Fundraiser_2 = ?, Fundraiser_3 = ?, Fundraiser_4 = ?, WHERE ID = ?";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fname_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MI", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mi_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lname_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = address1_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CityStateZip", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = address2_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PG", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pg_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HomePN", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = homePN_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkPN", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = workPN_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CellPN", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cellPN_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@YEmail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = yemail_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PGEmail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pgemail_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = age_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", OleDbType.Date).Value = bd_picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HS", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = hs_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Grade", OleDbType.Integer).Value = grade_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrevExp", OleDbType.Integer).Value = prevexp_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSize", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ssize;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Allergies", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = food_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MedConditions", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = special_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Avail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = week1_tb.Text + "," + week2_tb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstDep", OleDbType.Date).Value = deposit_picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecDep", OleDbType.Date).Value = second_picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ThirdDep", OleDbType.Date).Value = third_picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fundraiser_1", OleDbType.Date).Value = fund1Picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fundraiser_2", OleDbType.Date).Value = fund2Picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fundraiser_3", OleDbType.Date).Value = fund3Picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fundraiser_4", OleDbType.Date).Value = fund4Picker.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = idTB.Text;

        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        try
        {
            myCon.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem opening connection!\n" + ex.Message, "Exception");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Specifically, try to bring your code samples down to a more managable size. It's quite possible that in doing so, you would have found the answer to this yourself.

Comment: just a suggestion- when debugging syntax errors, work on a smaller set, updating 1 field instead of all of them.  it's easier that way.

Comment: @Michael: How do you make this smaller without changing the meaning of the code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you don't. Instead, like Beth said, you either pretty much rip it all out and start adding things back until it breaks, or you remove parts until it starts working. Either way, you will likely find the error in fairly short order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a comma before the WHERE clause in your sql.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Youth SET FName = ?, MI = ?, LName = ?, Street = ?, 
    CityStateZip = ?, PG = ?, HomePN = ?, WorkPN = ?, CellPN = ?, YEmail = ?, 
    PGEmail = ?, Age = ?, DOB = ?, HS = ?, Grade = ?, PrevExp = ?, SSize = ?, 
    Allergies = ?, MedConditions = ?, Avail = ?, FirstDep = ?, SecDep = ?, 
    ThirdDep = ?, Fundraiser_1 = ?, Fundraiser_2 = ?, Fundraiser_3 = ?, 
    Fundraiser_4 = ?,  <<--- extra comma
    WHERE ID = ?";
```

Comment: wow! thank you!! most likely a copy-paste type of error since the sql statement is so long, but thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your error (or at least one of them) is right here:

Fundraiser_4 = **?,** Where ...

remove the , after the `?`